# Sum only if number 3 in another column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum

Can someone help me 'tweak'  this formula to only 'sum' if it sees a '3' in column AP? =SumCellsByColor(B27:AL27, $AV$4) or change the below code

Your help would be very much appreciated

```
Function GetCellColor(xlRange As Range)
    Dim indRow, indColumn As Long
    Dim arResults()

    Application.Volatile

    If xlRange Is Nothing Then
        Set xlRange = Application.ThisCell
    End If

    If xlRange.Count > 1 Then
      ReDim arResults(1 To xlRange.Rows.Count, 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count)
       For indRow = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count
         For indColumn = 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count
           arResults(indRow, indColumn) = xlRange(indRow, indColumn).Interior.Color
         Next
       Next
     GetCellColor = arResults
    Else
     GetCellColor = xlRange.Interior.Color
    End If
End Function

Function GetCellFontColor(xlRange As Range)
    Dim indRow, indColumn As Long
    Dim arResults()

    Application.Volatile

    If xlRange Is Nothing Then
        Set xlRange = Application.ThisCell
    End If

    If xlRange.Count > 1 Then
      ReDim arResults(1 To xlRange.Rows.Count, 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count)
       For indRow = 1 To xlRange.Rows.Count
         For indColumn = 1 To xlRange.Columns.Count
           arResults(indRow, indColumn) = xlRange(indRow, indColumn).Font.Color
         Next
       Next
     GetCellFontColor = arResults
    Else
     GetCellFontColor = xlRange.Font.Color
    End If

End Function

Function CountCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByColor = cntRes
End Function

Function SumCellsByColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range)
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes

    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Interior.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Interior.Color Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    SumCellsByColor = sumRes
End Function

Function CountCellsByFontColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range) As Long
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim cntRes As Long

    Application.Volatile
    cntRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Font.Color Then
            cntRes = cntRes + 1
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    CountCellsByFontColor = cntRes
End Function

Function SumCellsByFontColor(rData As Range, cellRefColor As Range)
    Dim indRefColor As Long
    Dim cellCurrent As Range
    Dim sumRes

    Application.Volatile
    sumRes = 0
    indRefColor = cellRefColor.Cells(1, 1).Font.Color
    For Each cellCurrent In rData
        If indRefColor = cellCurrent.Font.Color Then
            sumRes = WorksheetFunction.Sum(cellCurrent, sumRes)
        End If
    Next cellCurrent

    SumCellsByFontColor = sumRes
End Function
```

Comment: I would look at the sumifs() function and include the color function as one of the criteria

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to see a result of SumCellsByColor only if at least one cell in column AP is equal to 3?

If yes, then I think a simple IF formula should help:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(AP:AP,3),sumcellsbycolor(B27:AL27, $AV$4),0)
```