# Only show the sum of a column if there are at least 3 records in another column

Tags: excel, count, countif, sumifs

I have 3 Columns of data.  Column E = Duration.  The user will enter a number of days (Duration) for 20 employees.  Column F = Pay.  List of wage for each employee.  Column R = Pay Total.  This is a calculated field based on the number of days (Duration) and the employees pay (Pay).

To keep my employees from finding out their coworkers pay I only want to see a sum for Column C if there are at least 3 records in Column A.

I found this [Sum only if 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55195541/sum-only-if-number-3-in-another-column.)
From that answer I tried to use =IF(COUNTIF(E2:E15,">2"),SUM(R2:R15))

What this does is only returns records with a duration of greater than 2 days.  I don't care about the number of days.  I want the indicator to be that there are 3 cells populated in this column.

I think the only issue with the formula is the CountIF part.  I need to know what I should use to count cells not days.

[Screenshot of My Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e44mR.jpg)

In the image above you can see that it's returning a sum bc both records are greater than 2.  Like I said before I don't care what number is in the cell I just want to see the sum if there are more than 2 cells populated in that column.

Thanks for any help

Comment: In your first paragraph, you are referencing columns E, F and R. And in your second paragraph, you are referencing columns A and C. I didn't see any data in columns A and C in your sample sheet screenshot.
Could you please clarify on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of the question, I came up with this solution. Give it a try.

```
=IF(COUNT($E$2:$E$15)>2,SUM($R$2:$R$15), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula would give what you want
=IF(COUNTA(E2:E15)>2,SUM(R2:R15),"")
This would show sum only if count of non empty cells is greater than 2 in Range "E2:E15" else it would show empty.